# Angular injection error AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken Platform ID`

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm using angularfire2 module. I have created FireQueryModule which is calling angularfire2 module. FireQueryModule I have injected in my AppModule.

Flow:  **AppModule -> FireQueryModule -> angularfire2**

If I us AngularFirestore Service in my FireQueryService I'm getting an error

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken Platform ID]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AngularFirestore -> InjectionToken Platform ID]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken Platform ID!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:979)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1232)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1182)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:1077)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:9217)
    at _createClass (core.js:9270)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:9234)
```

**Module Code**

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FireQueryService } from './services/firebase.service';
import { FirebaseAppConfig, AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@NgModule({})
export class FireQueryModule {
  static forRoot(config: FirebaseAppConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AngularFirestoreModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config)
      ],
      providers: [AngularFirestore]
    })
    class RootModule { }
    return {
      ngModule: RootModule,
      providers: [FireQueryService]
    };
  }
}
```

**Service Code**

```
@Injectable()
export class FireQueryService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { } // error here if i comment it works
}
```

I'm not getting where it's breaking.

Comment: It seems you're importing neither the `BrowserModule` or `ServerModule` from `@angular/platform-*` into your module, can you try doing that and see if it changes the error at all?

Comment: @JamesDaniels Thanks, It's working but now I'm getting another error `NullInjectorError: No provider for Console!`

Comment: @RahulSharma I've got the same issue with `No provider for Console!` did you ever figure out what caused it?

Comment: Same error here, and for information you can't import BrowserModule in custom lib module

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, how to solve it:

My Lib Module :

```
@NgModule({})
export class DomainLibModule {
  static forRoot(config: FirebaseAppConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config)
      ],
      providers: [AngularFireDatabase]
    })
    class RootModule { }
    return {
      ngModule: RootModule,
      providers: [DomainLibService]
    };
  }
}
```

My Lib Package.json :

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "6.x.x",
    "@angular/core": "6.x.x",
    "@angular/fire": "5.x.x",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.x.x",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.x.x",
    "firebase": "5.x.x",
    "rxjs": "6.x.x"
  }
```

So all my dependencies are on my application. I added platform-browser & platform-browser-dynamics because they are dependencies of AngularFire (I don't know if it's important)

**The most important is probably here**, in my app tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "./node_modules/@angular/*" // It could be an other path
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So what was the solution there? Trying the same approach but doesn't work for me. And by the way how do you then use that nested library's module?